# How to use anchor in rails to see error msg after submiting contact form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, anchor, contact-form

I'm new to rails and after reading first chapters of Ruby on Rails Tutorial I'm trying to setup simple one-pager with contact form in the lowest section of the page. I made it work, it's sending emails after submitting the form correctly. Unfortunately, if your input is incorrect, page will render again, but view will stay on the top of the page. User will not be able to see he made a mistake unless he scroll the page down to see the form again (there is error message rendering above the contact form) - which is not very useful. Also if input is correct, page will render again and stay on top, but I still didn't set any confirmation message for that option.

I know that there is also flash option but I didn't figure it out yet. If you think that this is quick and clean option please let me know how to set it.

Here is the code of my app:

static_pages_controller.rb:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :setup_contact_form

  def home
  end

  def submit_form
    @contact_form.attributes = contact_form_params

    if @contact_form.save
      redirect_to action: :home
    else
      render :home
    end
  end

  private
  def setup_contact_form
    @contact_form = ContactForm.new
  end

  def contact_form_params
    params.require(:contact_form).permit(:name, :email, :phone, :message)
  end
end
```

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'static_pages#home'

  resources :static_pages, only: [:home] do
    collection do
      post :submit_form
      get :home
    end
  end
```

contact form layout from home.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @contact_form, :url => submit_form_static_pages_path(@contact_form, :anchor => 'form') do |f| %>
```

I think that the routes.rb syntax is not best, but I don't know how to correct it to make it work and after invalid submission, render page  correctly focused on contact form and error message.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add an anchor on a render call only on a redirect_to call. This is problematic for you because you specifically want to display the errors which will not be possible with a redirect_to.

Have you considered using AJAX instead? This will mean that the user won't have to observe / wait for the page to load after they submit their contact enquiry.

That said, if AJAX isn't for you perhaps you could use JavaScript to scroll to the form when there's errors:

```
<!-- in your view -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('.error-message').length) {
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(".error-message").offset().top
      }, 3000);
    };
  });
</script>
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/patrickfq/jb7zv7m9/